# Connect to WiFi why .disconnect() than reconnect()?

Tags: java, android, wifi, disconnect, reconnect

All- I have an app in which I want the user to be able to connect with a WiFi network. I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically) and I had the app being able to disconnect and than reconnect (in other words I had the right SSID and password), but his is not exactly what I want to do. I want to just connect if not connected already and not do anything if already connected. When I turned WiFi off (via settings) and than ran my app, nothing happened. So than I tried this

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiConfiguration wc = new WifiConfiguration();        
    String networkSSID = SSID;
    String networkPass = PASS;      
    wc.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\""; 
    wc.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPass +"\"";
    wc.hiddenSSID = true;
    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
        if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {            

        wifi.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true); //Look here

        break;

        }           
     }
```

versus this

```
//Above code the same
    for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
            if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {            
            wifi.disconnect(); //See, disconnect..
            wifi.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifi.reconnect();  //Than reconnect!
            break;

            }           
         }
```

This change did nothing though (even when the WiFi was on). So my question is **how can I just turn WiFi on if not on already and do nothing if already on (I know I have to use if statements so I am just looking for the WiFi specific code)?** Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you simply asking how to turn on wifi in android programmatically?

[How to programmatically turn off WiFi on Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device)

to summarize:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 

boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
if(!wifiEnabled){
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks for your time and effort!