# How to set a static IP for new WiFi configuration?

Tags: java, android, static, ip, wifi

Again stuck on the same problem.

I have found around that we can set static system settings like this:

```
System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP, "1"); // to define it use static ip's
System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_IP,"192.168.1.15");
System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_NETMASK,"255.255.255.0");
System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1,"192.168.1.1");
System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_GATEWAY,"192.168.1.1");
```

But **No Success!**

I don't understand that when to set these settings?

Should I do it before the wifi configuration creation or after saving the wifi configuration or even before activating it or after it?

However, I have tried the all possible cases from my side and when I check Android WiFi settings, I see it's still on DHCP.

A previous question i.e. [How to configue a static IP address, netmask, gateway programmatically on Android 3.x or 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10278461/how-to-configue-static-ip-netmask-gateway-programmatically-on-android-3-x-or-4) has completely ruined my android device and now it can't switch 
ON its WiFi anymore.

I also tried static IP on my HTC phone and no success, its always in DHCP mode!

Do I need to call a "**reconnect**" command? If yes, then in which way?

Comment: Normally the right solution is to leave your Android device alone (DHCP) and instead feed its MAC address into your DHCP server's configuration and have it feed back the "static" data.

Comment: I see I can set a stati IP with android wifi settings... I really don't understand why google make these things so complicated. Anyway, I'm connecting to a very simple wifi microchip that can't handle feeds of mac address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more than a year, I give up with setting a static IP (or DHCP, DNS, ...). Simply it's not possible, or, better, it's not allowed (from an arbitrary application).

Someone says:

*"You could use NDK - this gives you low-level access to Linux under Android. Warning: don't expect this to be documented or supported. They might even ban you from Android Market (I know I would)"*

For those who want to have some expriences with NDK, here is the a link:

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Good luck, and give some feedback if you find something interesting!

Answer (score 4):

I  think you it should look like:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_IP,"192.168.1.15");
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1, "192.168.1.1");        
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_GATEWAY, "192.168.1.1");   
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_NETMASK, "255.255.255.0");                 
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP, "1");
```

And don't forget the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
```

Regarding the WiFi problem that your device had, you can try switching the WIFI on programmatically. This post might be helpful:
[How to programmatically turn off WiFi on Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device)

Comment: try setting WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP to 0 in the beginning, and then set it to 1 in the end.

Comment: did it works for you? Maybe it a problem related to my access point. however it's still on dhcp...

Comment: btw, have you tried connecting manually to the wifi? I mean, going to settings, wifi and setting the ip, mask, gateway, etc. there? If it does not work there, maybe the problem is not on the device...

Comment: yes it works... but I think Android do some "dirty" things that are not allowed to developers

Comment: regarding WiFi problem on my old device... anytime I try to do something with wifi the system reboots!

Comment: are you using this approach successfully?

Comment: @Zedot: Are you having success on Android OS ver.3 & above using your this code?

Comment: I'm compiling with 2.3, and used in Android 4.0.1: no success!