# Android - wlan0 doesn't exist

Tags: android

I'm using galaxy s2 (ROM 4.1.2). I turn off wifi using the command :

```
netcfg
```

The above command lists all the available NIC. But it doesn't have "wlan0" in it. I use :

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

it shows :

> error: SIOCGIFFLAGS (No such device)

Until I turn my wifi function on, the `wlan0` added.

Now I'm currently developing the hotspot application so I need to config some options for the `wlan0` interface. In my galaxy s1 (ROM 4.2.2). Even when the WIFI function turns off. It still show `wlan0` as:

```
wlan0    DOWN  0.0.0.0/0   0x00001002 00:26:37:63:d8:ab
```

So my question is: Is there anyway I can add `wlan0` even when i don't use WIFI function?

Comment: You can enable wifi programmatically, if this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. But I want to enable by command !!!

Answer (score 2):

i know i am 1 year late but still .... i just installed busybox and a terminal app and checked all the available interfaces with the following command

```
busybox ifconfig -a
```

what i got to know is that the wireless interface for my phone was named as "eth0" instead of "wlan0"

Hope it helps .. better late than never .