# how to enable Mobile Data on BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-internet

I am working on BroadcastReceiver app, and I am trying to enable the  Mobile Data internet. I have code to enable the wifi:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

and how do I make it to mobile intenet?

Comment: Have you set the required permissions? Take a look at this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11555457/3593126.