# WiFi on during airplane mode in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, airplane-mode

I want to turn on airplane mode but WiFi should remain turn on. I want to do it using programming in Android. How it can be done?

In my application I want to turn on airplane mode but my application needs WiFi connectivity so WiFi should not be turned off.

Comment: network connectivity goes down when in airplane mode right?? that's the idea

Answer (score 1):

By combining [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device) SO answer. Turn on Airplane Mode with the first, turn on Wifi (only) with the second. But there's a caveat: Turning on Airplane Mode requires a special permission in Android 4.2 and beyond that is not available to non-system app makers, so this solution will only work for pre-4.2 devices.