# Update network state programmatically

Tags: java, android, telephony

I want to change the status of the cell network where the device is connected. I could get the information about which cell is currently using and the technology of the cell using `TelephonyManager`. I want to change this state, for example, to close the network connection as we could do using Wifi.

**Important:** by network I mean the Network cell the device recive from the carrier and I want to cancel the network and the internet data too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863509/how-to-programmatically-turn-off-wifi-on-android-device?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: As I explain, I want to change the cell network, not the Wifi network. That answer is only for Wifi state.

Comment: That's not possible. You should redirected to sim card settings in the app