# Getting mobile data usage when WiFI On Using TrafficStats

Tags: java, android

My English is not good!. I had a problem, I'm trying to get mobile data usage and using TrafficStats of android. I have downloaded the downloaded, 
uploaded data using:

```
public long d = 0;
public long u = 0
private void getSpeed() {
    totalDownload += ((((TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() - d) / 1024) / 1024));
    totalUpload += ((((TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() - u) / 1024) / 1024));

    total += totalDownload + totalUpload;

    tvDownload.setText( totalDownload + "Mb" );
    tvUpload.setText( totalUpload + " Mb" );
    tvTotal.setText( total + "Mb" );
    Log.d( "getSpeed", "totalData: " + totalDownload );

    d = TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes();
    u = TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes();

}
```

Everything Ok, but when I turn on Wifi, the method returns 0/0. How to get mobile data usage when using wifi?

Comment: you can turn off WiFi programmatically. Before calling this method turn off Wifi and at end of the method you can turn on WiFi.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8863540/3154636 refer this

Comment: I want get mobile data when wifi on :3