# How to open Settings panel in Android Q programmatically?

Tags: android, android-settings, android-10.0

As per **Android Q** new features, there is a **inline settings panel** showing key connectivity settings that lets the user modify different connectivity settings such as **airplane mode, wifi, volume, NFC and internet connectivity**.

How can I open that **settings panel programmatically** from my app? like in screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is very simple and easy to implement using Settings panel API available in Android Q.

Simple we need to trigger intent with one of the new [Settings.Panel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Panel#constants_2) actions.

### To open Internet Connectivity Panel:

[image]

**Java:**

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    Intent panelIntent = new Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 545)
}
```

**Kotlin:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 545)
}
```

### To open Volume control panel:

[image]

**Java:**

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    Intent panelIntent = new Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_VOLUME)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 545)
}
```

**Kotlin:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_VOLUME)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 545)
}
```

### To open WIFI panel:

[image]

**Java:**

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    Intent panelIntent = new Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_WIFI)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 545)
}
```

**Kotlin:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_WIFI)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 545)
}
```

### To open NFC panel:

[image]

**Java:**

```java
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    Intent panelIntent = new Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_NFC)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 545)
}
```

**Kotlin:**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    val panelIntent = Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_NFC)
    startActivityForResult(panelIntent, 545)
}
```

Here you can check more about settings panel from Android official doc:

1) https://developer.android.com/preview/features#settings-panels

2) https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Panel

Comment: What is 545 here in the call to `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: @AdeleGoldberg It is just request code for starting activity for result so that we the started activity returns a result in `onActivityResult`, you can check for which request this result is returned.

Comment: @BirjuVachhani It is also mentioned in the docs "We are planning to introduce an AndroidX wrapper for this functionality. When called on devices running Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, the wrapper will open the most-appropriate page in the Settings app." Is the AndroidX wrapper introduced yet?

Comment: @MehulKanzariya Apparently, the wrapper idea has been canceled: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/f574wo/weekly_questions_thread_february_17_2020/fi36io9/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

Comment: Will it work with android services?